# How to write more than 7 columns into a csv file by IDL?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have been tried to write 8 columns in a CSV file by using IDL, but seems the maximum columns that I can wrote is 7?

```
IDL> write_csv,ffout,date_time,tmin_tmax,precp,wind,rh,sun_hrs,glb_rad,net_rad
WRITE_CSV: Incorrect number of arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `WRITE_CSV` indicates you can write up to 8 columns, which works for me:

```
x = findgen(10)
write_csv, 'test.csv', x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x
```

In any case, if you need to write more columns, it is easy enough to use `PRINTF` to output each line:

```
for i = 0L, n_lines - 1L do begin
  printf, lun, a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i], g[i], h[i], $
          format='(%"%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f")'
endfor
```

You can change the format codes as appropriate, or use the Fortran-style format codes as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your input arrays are one-dimensional you can just concatenate them (and do an additional transpose):

```
a = FINDGEN(3)
b = TRANSPOSE([ [a], [a], [a], [a], [a], [a], [a], [a], [a], [a] ])
WRITE_CSV, 'test.csv', b
```